# How to have different sizes for infobox in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using infobox (control which inherits for google.maps.InfoWindow) to create infowindows. But I'm having a problem because I have different sizes of infobox so I can't use the width CSS property, and I need to know the width to modify  pixeloffset to situated an icon in the middle of infobox.

I'm using Google API V3 and using this JavaScript code:

```
var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
    boxText.innerHTML = alertJson.innerHTML;
    var myOptions = {
             content: boxText
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: "280px"
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: { 
              background: "url('img/tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
              ,opacity: 0.75
              //,width: "280px"
             }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
    };
```

tipbox.gif is the icon which I need to situated in the middle of infobox, and pixelOffset the property which I need to modify.

I've tried to change width property to auto but It hasn't worked.

Comment: Please post your current code and how you are trying to put that icon in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you open the boxes on a marker-event:**

store all specific data(width, content, etc.) inside the marker-object.  You'll be able to access them inside the event-callback and can set the options for the infobox before you open it.